# P5 DOM function 'select' is not being found, even though I've imported p5.dom.js

Tags: javascript, html, dom, flask, p5.js

Here is my **HTML**:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='lib/p5.js') }}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='lib/p5.dom.js') }}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"  src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/grid.js') }}?{{version_num}}"></script>
```

The first two imports don't throw an error. My setup() function in grid.js does, however.

part of **grid.js**

```
function setup() {
    smooth();
    canvas = createCanvas(windowWidth, windowWidth * 3/2);
    textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
    textSize(fontSize);
    frameRate(32);
    fill(0, 0, 0, 40);


    inputs = select('.word_entry');
    console.log(inputs)
}
```

Yet, when I try and call the built in `select` function of p5.dom.js, I get this error. 
What's going on??

**Error message**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: select is not defined
at setup (grid.js?1.0.3:17)
at p5.<anonymous> (p5.js:217)
at p5.<anonymous> (p5.js:190)
at new p5 (p5.js:342)
at _globalInit (p5.js:5761)
```

**Edit:** Don't mind the url_for syntax, that's just flask. I'm sure that lib/p5.dom.js is being loaded, because placing it before the lib/p5.js throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still curious about what went wrong, but I fixed this by just downloading the 'complete' version of P5 and getting rid of the p5.dom.js import line.

Comment: p5.dom.js was merged into p5.js after v1.0: https://github.com/processing/p5.js/issues/4831#issuecomment-703727937